# Not sure if I am using eager loading correctly, getting null on a relationship that exists

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I am having a tough time with this eloquent query and hoping someone can help me out.

The query works fine with the exception of the author relationship, it returns null when I know the author and the relationship both exist. (there are no books without authors in the database)

Here is the code in question:

```
//  BookController.php
$categories = array(1,2,3,4);
$audience_age = 15;

$books = Book::with(array('categories','author'))->whereHas('categories', function($q) use ($categories, $audience_age) 
{
    $q->whereIn('id', $categories)->where('audience_age', '<=', $audience_age)->where('status', '=', 'active');
})->take(50)->get(array('id','data'));


//  Book.php
public function author()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('Author');
}


//  Author.php
public function books()
{
    return $this->hasMany('Book');
}


//  authors migration
Schema::create('authors', function($table)
{
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->string('name');
    $table->string('status');
    $table->timestamps();
    $table->softDeletes();
});         


//  books migration
Schema::create('books', function($table)
{
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->integer('author_id')->unsigned();
    $table->foreign('author_id')->references('id')->on('authors');
    $table->string('name');
    $table->text('data');
    $table->string('status');
    $table->timestamps();
    $table->softDeletes();
});
```

I verified that the relationship does exist and work by picking a particular Book, ID#40, and ran this query separately:

```
print_r(Book::find(40)->author->toJSON());
```

The author was found without issue when loading it that way.

I have been using my mad googl'in skills for a few hours trying to figure this one out but so far nothing.. any help would be very appreciated!

UPDATE --

After looking at DB::getQueryLog() I saw that the ID of the author in the query is set to 0
    ["query"]=> string(55) "select * from `authors` where `authors`.`id` in (?)" ["bindings"]=> array(1) { [0]=> int(0) } } }

Comment: The easier way to figure this out is print out the SQL statement that is generated behind the scene. Can you print out DB::getQueryLog() and see what's Eloquent is churning out?

Comment: Calling it how it returns `null` in the relationship?

Comment: It looks like the ID of the author is not set in the Author query, it is set to 0:  select * from `authors` where `authors`.`id` in (?)" ["bindings"]=> array(1) { [0]=> int(0) }

Comment: normally if I eager load multiple relationships i just pass a string worth of models ie with('categories', 'author'), have you tried it without the array?

Comment: Yeah, I did try that.  The query works both ways but still does not return the author

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not figure out how to do it using the ORM, but I was able to get the query working by using DB::raw.

If I find out how to make it work within the ORM I will come back and update my answer.

For now, here is how I pulled it off:

```
$results = DB::select(DB::raw("SELECT b.id, b.data, au.id as author_id, GROUP_CONCAT(c.id) as categories
    FROM books b
    INNER JOIN book_category bc ON bc.book_id = b.id
    INNER JOIN categories c ON c.id = bc.category_id 
    INNER JOIN authors au ON au.id = b.author_id 
    WHERE c.id IN (1,2,3,4) 
    LIMIT 2"));
```

Answer (score 2):

The only problem with you code was not getting `foreign key` linking `Book` and `Author`:

```
$books = Book:: ... ->get(array('id','data'));
```

This way Eloquent doesn't know what to look for, thus it sets sensible default `0`.

**Simply enclose `author_id` in the `select`:**

```
$books = Book:: ... ->get(array('id', 'data', 'author_id'));
```

and it will work as expected.

Comment: 6 months later I ran into the same problem and your answer helped me again.  Would +1 again